# Pointer to a C++ structure

Tags: c++, struct

If I create a structure in C++ like this:

```
typedef struct node {
    int item;
    int occurrency;
};
```

I know that a structure is allocated in memory using successive spaces, but what is the name of the structure (`node` in this example)? A simple way to give a name to the structure?

Comment: It's a data type, a special case of a `class` ... Not sure what you're after here. What does the way the `struct` is represented in memory have to do with the name of the concept?

Comment: and why is the title "Pointer to a C++ structure"? The question has nothing to do with pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`node` is the name of the **type**. You can have multiple **objects** of that type:

```
struct node {
  int item;
  int occurrency;
};
node a;
node b;
```

In this example, both `a` and `b` have the same type (==`node`), which means that they have the same layout in memory. There's both an `a.item` and a `b.item`.

Comment: Perfet, this is what I mean. In this case, what are a and b? A pointer? A null value? I think to have wrong my initial question...

Comment: @unNaturhal: They're both objects, i.e. areas of memory. `&a` would be a pointer to that area of memory. The objects are not initialized; you must write to them before you can read their values back.

Comment: Please, could you draw me an example of memory allocation of a struct? I haven't understood `*a` which value gives back :/

Comment: `*a` doesn't make sense. You'd better consult [our C++ book list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you don't have to use `typedef` to name a structure type:

```
struct node {
    int item;
    int occurrency;
};
```

is enough.

A pointer to an instance of that struct would be defined as `node* mypointer;`

E.g: You want to allocate a new instance with `new`:

```
node* mypointer = new node;
```

Answer (score 3):

In C

```
struct node {
    int item;
    int occurrency;
};
```

is a tag, and by itself, it doesn't represent a type.
That is why you cannot do

```
node n;
```

You have to do

```
struct node n;
```

So, to give it a "type name", many C programmers use a `typedef`

```
typedef struct node {
    int item;
    int occurrency;
} node;
```

That way you can do

```
node n;
```

Instead of

```
struct node n;
```

Also, you can omit the tag and do the following

```
typedef struct {
    int item;
    int occurrency;
} node;
```

However, in C++ this all changes, the `typedef` syntax is no longer needed. In C++ classes and structs are considered to be user-defined types by default, so you can just use the following

```
struct node {
    int item;
    int occurrency;
};
```

And declare nodes like this

```
node n;
```